# Is it possible to check quality of solution in an optimization problem? If yes, how?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints, constraint-programming

The optimization problem is non-linear, convex and constrained. The optimal solution definitely exists and I'm not sure if it is unique or not. To be specific, the problem is called Alternating Current Optimal Power Flow problem. It is a non-convex problem which I have relaxed into a convex one.

First, when I say quality of solution, I mean that it is the measure of how close is the solution obtained to the optimal solution.

1. Is it possible to calculate that measure without knowing the optimal solution? If yes, how?
2. If no, what are the other definitions for 'Quality of the Solution' and how to measure quality in those cases?

Comment: For a good answer to your question to be possible, I think you should be more specific about what sort of optimization problems you are considering.  Linear or nonlinear? Constrained? Convex? Discrete, continuous or mixed?  Is it known that the optimal solution exists and/or is unique?

Comment: I've made the changes. Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: First, you have a contradiction. In the first sentance you say that it is convex, and then you say it is not. Second, I am working on AC OPF myself, and it is non-convex. Please fix. Third, I believe the only measure you have is the duality gap. I am not aware of a better measure of optimality.

Comment: @Alex It is a non convex problem, true. But I have modified the problem into a convex one. I am not trying to find a global solution so I think it is safe to call the problem convex. It would be really helpful if you could try to answer the questions I asked. So you're saying duality gap is a way to measure quality?

Comment: Then there is something missing. Are you trying to measure how close it is to an optimal solution of the original problem or to an optimal solution of the relaxation

Comment: I didn't decide that. Say both. What should be my approaches?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. What is the meaning of "quality" for you? What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: I tend to analyze my solution and algorithm. I have a solution but I have no evidence to show that the solution I obtained is good and the algorithm works good. I mean I can verify if they are within constraints. But that still doesn't tell me how good the obtained solution is or how close it is to the optimal value.